# CompositeItemReader in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In Spring Batch, in the job-request.xml file you can have the chunk's writer run a "compositeItemWriter" which looks something like this:

```
<bean id="compositeItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref bean="writer1" />
            <ref bean="writer2" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I was wondering if there's anything similar for readers? I tried using org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream but apparently delegates does not exist as a property. Putting "reader1" or "reader2" in the delegates property list in compositeItemWriter similarly does not work (cannot convert readers to writers)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: afaik there is no official support for this feature, but you can take a look at https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch-examples-readers search for "compositeItemReader"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MultiResourceItemReader reads items from multiple resources sequentially:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html

It will look like:

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="LIST_OF_FILES" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="itemReaderDelegate" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've done a SQL trick to make up for it in the meantime but this will definitely come in handy in the future.